# Put database field in the RHS on the WHERE condition?

Tags: abap, opensql

How we can write the below `WHERE`?

```
SELECT * FROM acdoca
WHERE koart = @(COND #( blart = 'DY' THEN 'D' ELSE 'S' ) )
```

It does not recognize the field name BLART. How can we pass it?
Thanks
Elias

EDIT: here is the whole WHERE:

```
WHERE acdoca~rldnr = '0L' AND
      acdoca~rbukrs = @company_code AND
      acdoca~belnr IN @document_no_range AND
      acdoca~gjahr = @year AND
      acdoca~koart = @(COND #( blart = 'DY' THEN 'D' ELSE 'S' ) )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

​A [Host Expression `@( ... )`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopen_sql_host_expressions.htm) is only interpreted at ABAP side, there is absolutely no interaction with the database server, the expression is evaluated and the SQL statement is updated with the result before it is sent to the database.

If I understand well what you want to achieve, this should work:

```
  SELECT * FROM acdoca
      WHERE ( blart = 'DY' and koart = 'D' )
         OR ( blart <> 'DY' and koart = 'S' )
      INTO TABLE @DATA(itab).
```

NB: if I didn't understand well and you really want a Host Expression, a valid syntax would be this one:

```
DATA blart TYPE acdoca-blart.
SELECT * FROM acdoca
      WHERE koart = @( COND #( WHEN blart = 'DY' THEN 'D' ELSE 'S' ) )
      INTO TABLE @DATA(itab).
```

EDIT: here is the complement to the EDIT of the question, the whole correct WHERE would be:

```
WHERE acdoca~rldnr = '0L' AND
      acdoca~rbukrs = @company_code AND
      acdoca~belnr IN @document_no_range AND
      acdoca~gjahr = @year AND
  ( ( acdoca~blart <> 'DY' AND acdoca~koart = 'S' ) OR
    ( acdoca~blart = 'DY' AND acdoca~koart = 'D' ) )
```

Comment: With the correction I made to my question by adding the whole where I believe that wee need 2 sets of parentheses separated by the OR.   But I want to ask you how it will work the HOST as the BLART may change in the select sometimes is DY and sometimes NOT.. Thanks

Comment: I tried to explain how Host Expression works, that it's evaluated by ABAP and not by the database server. Only the result is sent to the database server. I don't think you really want a Host Expression. As you say "HOST" and "change in the select sometimes" in the same sentence, I guess my answer wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks Sandra. Can you please put the OR in a parenthesis in order to be more accurate as I didn't write the whole where clause.